# If statement in R combined with for

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to create an if statement in R.
This is my starting table:

[image]

I have tried the following which gives a plausible result:

```
GSPC$GSPC.DIFF <- for( i in 1:length(GSPC$GSPC.Weekdaynr) ) {
    if( GSPC$GSPC.Weekdaynr[i] > 4 ) {
        GSPC.DIFF <- append(GSPC.DIFF,5)
    } else {
        GSPC.DIFF <- append(GSPC.DIFF, "")
    }
}
```

[image]

But changing statment 1 to append(GSPC.DIFF,GSPC$GSPC.Close)

```
GSPC$GSPC.DIFF <- for ( i in 1:length(GSPC$GSPC.Weekdaynr) ) {
    if ( GSPC$GSPC.Weekdaynr[i] > 4 ) {
        GSPC.DIFF <- append(GSPC.DIFF, GSPC$GSPC.Close)
    } else {
        GSPC.DIFF <- append(GSPC.DIFF, "")
    }
}
```

Gives the following:

[image]

do anyone know why it is not giving value to every five lines like in the first case?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a simple `ifelse()`, i.e. `ifelse(GSPC$GSPC.Weekdaynr[i] > 4, GSPC$GSPC.Close, "")`. Does that do what you want? Also, people will be better able to help you with a [mcve]. In particular, you could provide (at least a subset of) your data if you [edit] your question to include the output of `dput(head(GSPC, 10))` rather than posting pictures of your data, which people can't copy and paste to work with your data in their own R session.

Comment: Thanks, I did not get the answer I was hoping for.. I used this formula - > GSPC$GSPC <- for(i in 1:length(GSPC$GSPC.Weekdaynr)) ifelse(GSPC$GSPC.Weekdaynr[i] > 4, GSPC$GSPC.Test <- 0, GSPC$GSPC.Test <- 1) Output: structure(list(GSPC.Open = c(3244.669922, 3226.360107), GSPC.High = c(3258.139893, 
3246.149902), GSPC.Low = c(3235.530029, 3222.340088), GSPC.Close = c(3257.850098, 
3234.850098), GSPC.Volume = c(3458250000, 3461290000), GSPC.Adjusted = c(3257.850098, 
3234.850098), GSPC.Weekdaynr = c(4, 5), GSPC.Test = c(0, 0)), row.names = c("2020-01-02", 
"2020-01-03"), class = "data.frame")

Comment: in case of GSPC.Weekdaynr 5 it should say 0 and in case of 4 it should say 1 (Both says 0 for some reason)                                                                                                                                         GSPC$GSPC <- for(i in 1:length(GSPC$GSPC.Weekdaynr)) ifelse(GSPC$GSPC.Weekdaynr[i] > 4, GSPC$GSPC.Test <- 0, GSPC$GSPC.Test <- 1)

Comment: Also statement 1 should be a formula in the end result = (DJI.Close - lag(DJI.Close))/lag(DJI.Close) * 100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very rarely you need explicit `for` loops in R. Using `for` loop and growing the vector in a loop using `append` is going to be highly inefficient.

There are many ways to do this, a simple way as suggested by @duckmayr is using `ifelse`.

For example, you can do :

```
GSPC$GSPC.DIFF1 <- with(GSPC, ifelse(GSPC.Weekdaynr > 4,5, NA))
GSPC$GSPC.DIFF2 <- with(GSPC, ifelse(GSPC.Weekdaynr > 4,GSPC.Close, NA))
```

Note that in your attempt when the condition was not satisfied (`GSPC.Weekdaynr > 4`), you were returning an empty value (`""`) but here I am returning `NA` since a column can only have one class, when you return an empty value it change all the numbers to string which cannot be used for further processing, returning `NA` would keep them as numbers.

Comment: Smooth solution, thanks :-)

Comment: Do you have any idea why the lag function is not working as expected in this formula (both of these gives same result (GSPC.Close-lag(GSPC.Close, k =5)) ) ? GSPC$GSPC.Test <- with(GSPC, ifelse(GSPC.Weekdaynr > 4,(GSPC.Close-lag(GSPC.Close, k =5))/lag(GSPC.Close, k =5)*100, NA))

Comment: No sorry, I don't know. Probably, you can ask new question for it.

Comment: Will do, thanks :) I checked the answer !